# What software is responsible to check permission of files to give access or not to users?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I want to verify that is it the responsibility of file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel is doing it when your program is using the open system call.

Comment: Kernel has many things in it. May I know what part of the kernel that does it? It seems like the open system call that do the checking.

Comment: The open system call is doing it indeed, I believe that is what I already wrote in my answer. If you want to know what precise part of the kernel is doing the job, start with reading from that function: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/namei.c#L2993